# wordpress too slow with wamp and xampp on localhost

Tags: wordpress, xampp, wamp

I have downloaded the latest WordPress version, but it is running too slow every request takes 2 minutes from the first time even before install any theme
my laptop is an i5 10th generation gaming laptop with 8GB ram so I think it is not a resource problem
I have tried some solutions like stopping cgi_module and adding these lines to php.ini

```
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
```

and adding this line to wp_config

```
define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', '1');
```

but no thing works do you have any ideas
I am using window 11

Comment: I don't think the problem is caused by them. I think it is caused by a plugin or theme you are running on the latest version of Wordpress. So, have you tried downgrading Wordpress? How does he react then?

Comment: @BatuhanZorbeyZengin thank you my friend, WordPress 5.5 has better performance for me  than WordPress 6, you saved my life